# How to take the parameter from URL scheme.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurl, url-scheme

I am using URL scheme in my iPhone app,from a page I switch user to safari,and a button click from Web page,I am reverting back to app
At that time ,some parameters are passed by the web page like

```
 myapp://parameter=1
```

How can I find this parameter from my app ?
I have placed a break point in

```
    -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)ur
```

but while revert back.it is not get called.

Comment: How do you launch your app? Try to type the url in safari. Do you return YES from this method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this `url host`  to find out the parameters, where parameters could be of any kind, anything after `http://` or custom tag `custom://` will be caught in the following code

```
 NSString *urlParameter = [[url host] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If you have multiple parameters then you could use `componentsSeparatedByString` method to separate the parameters

Comment: just use in this     `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` method, just try to NSLog the value there when you click the custom link, it will print out `parameter=1`

Comment: Do you have any idea how this can be achieved in vanilla c++? 
Is there an equivalent function in Carbon?

Answer (score 21):

```
NSString *query = [url query];
NSArray *queryComponents = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
```

Now you got all strings in queryComponents like

```
param1=value
```

Now you can get first value like that

```
NSArray *firstParam = [[queryComponents objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];

[firstParam objectAtIndex:0] is the name of param
[firstParam objectAtIndex:1] is value of the param
```

Comment: @Mert I have tried query for my custom links when I created, I never got anything inside query, might be because I had custom parameters after `customtag://` so i preferred using `[url host]`

Comment: If you have a URL like that customschema://myhost/?param=1&secondParam=2 it works. It is common, the urls look like this. I use myhost for different actions in my app like showAlert, showsomeview etc... Then I can check what to do

Comment: You can use it in your -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url method. You have the url here

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. this ll useful even if you had numbers of parameters and values in url.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xyz.com/result.php?data1=1123660801&data2=250072028055&presult=SUCCESS"];

NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
NSArray *queryItems = [components queryItems];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

for (NSURLQueryItem *item in queryItems)
{
    [dict setObject:[item value] forKey:[item name]];
}
```

Comment: this should be the answer, just make it more specific to answer the question.