# Open iOS app from Costom URL Schema and pass parameters using post method

Tags: ios, url, post, parameters, schema

can we pass a "POST" parameters along with custom URL schema to open an IOS application.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, although url parameters should be enough to pass simple data. I added a couple links below that should help you pass data using a custom url scheme.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html
http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

[How to take the parameter from URL scheme.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360478/how-to-take-the-parameter-from-url-scheme)